# How to fix the 415 / Unsupported media type error?

Tags: angular, http, post

I am using angular to make a POST. I have successfully done it in Postman, so I am now just trying to get it in my angular app.

When I am trying to make the request in angular I get a

```
Status Code: 415 / Unsupported Media Type
```

There is also a long error code in the console

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): HttpErrorResponse: {"headers":{"normalizedNames":{"_t":"Map","_i":{},"_s":0},"lazyUpdate":null},"status":415,"statusText":"Unsupported Media Type"
```

So in Postman I am able to successfully make the POST. I used the Postman built-in code option in order to get all of the headers correct, which looks something like this

```
"headers": {
    "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    "User-Agent": "PostmanRuntime/7.13.0",
    "Accept": "*/*",
    "Cache-Control": "no-cache",
    "Postman-Token": "4eac9c16-3e20-44d0-be8d-414ead01bdc6,107a109d-62dd-4b52-b84d-e60d3ad092c4",
    "cookie": "JSESSIONID=F09A8E826390A6B788B9E45E0E663ECD.pc4bsfapi06t",
    "accept-encoding": "gzip, deflate",
    "content-length": "2337",
    "Connection": "keep-alive",
    "cache-control": "no-cache"
```

I used the following headers:

```
"Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    "Accept": "*/*",
    "Cache-Control": "no-cache",
    "accept-encoding": "gzip, deflate",
    "content-length": "2337",
    "Connection": "keep-alive",
    "cache-control": "no-cache"
```

I set them by doing the following:

```
let idpOptions ={
           headers: new HttpHeaders({
              "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
              "Accept": "*/*",
              "Cache-Control": "no-cache",
              "accept-encoding": "gzip, deflate",
              "content-length": "2337",
              "Connection": "keep-alive",
              "cache-control": "no-cache"
              }),
          withCredentials: true,
        };
```

And then did:

```
 this.http.post(idpUrl, idpOptions)
```

I would expect this request to work since it is working in postman and I used, what I thought to be, all the necessary headers.

Comment: How did you set your HTTP header?

Comment: @youri I added in some code about how I defined headers

Comment: you have to call your POST like this: `this.http.post(idpUrl, null, idpOptions)`. Have a look at [Angular example](https://angular.io/guide/http#adding-headers).

Comment: @youri thank you! That fixed the 415 error. I am getting a different error now but that definitely helped move me forward. Thanks again!

Comment: @youri read about POSt requests in the documentation. So why does it have to be set to null here?

Comment: you have to set null because the second parameters define the request body. If you have to send data from a form through POST, you have to set the second paramaters based on your data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The HTTP post call is not correct, you second parameter is for the request body: https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpClient#post.

Change this:

```
this.http.post(idpUrl, idpOptions)
```

To this (assuming you don't need any request body):

```
this.http.post(idpUrl, null, idpOptions)
```

You can also have a look to the [Angular documentation](https://angular.io/guide/http#adding-headers).